# Facebook Pixel Bug - Can't send eventID through dynamic routing [Without Page Refresh]

Tags: javascript, gatsby, facebook-pixel

For some reason when I try to send the eventId parameter a second time after the page has loaded, the Facebook pixel is not picking it up even though the eventId has a value.

Any idea on how to solve this? I am using react with gatsby dynamic routing. Do I need to somehow reinstantiate fbq and if so, how?

This appears to only be an issue with the PageView event.

```
fbq("track", "PageView", { ...userData }, { eventId: eventId })
```

Answer (score 2):

Set this option true in place init Facebook Pixel:

```
fbq.disablePushState = true
fbq.allowDuplicatePageViews = true
```

Comment: This solves my problem for spa. Thanks!